# What are Lagrange multiplier and Dual decomposition methods?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, lagrange-multipliers, dual-decomposition

What are the Lagrange multiplier and Dual decomposition methods? How are these methods used in Machine Learning(ML) for Optimization?

Comment: A description of Lagrangian optimization and an example of its application to Machine Learning are available in [Andrew Ng's lectures notes on Support Vector Machine](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes3.pdf), which will answer all your questions.

Comment: Such questions will often get better answers at https://or.stackexchange.com/